# Mounted hook not being called in Nuxt component in production (full static)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a component that is included on a page in Nuxt.

This component has the following lifecycle hooks:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    created() { alert('oh hai!') },
    mounted() { alert('oh hai again!') }
}
</script>
```

This works fine in development. However when I export the site full static (nuxt generate) the code in the created and mounted hooks does not run -- the alerts never appear when the page is loaded.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out. Do the created/mounted lifecycle hooks get called on components if they are used on full static nuxt sites? If not, what is the recommended way to initialize the code that is used to control a component?

Comment: What if you try just a `console.log`? It possible that those 2 alerts are discarded since there is a first server side render then a client side hydration. Not sure how `alert` behaves in this situation. PS: `created` is available on both sides, while `mounted` is only available on client side: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/ Also, you did tried to build and run this locally or only hosting it somewhere when you test the generated build ?

Comment: hi Kissu -- same problem is exhibited with console.log -- interestingly the problem does not exist if i embed the component directly on a layout.  It only happens if I embed the component on a page.  (The hooks don't fire on a page root either.)

Comment: I have similar problem

Comment: Probabily in "static version" the components was no "mounted" but only "created".
For this reason over npn run dev "mounted" works, but in static generated not work.

Is only my supposion. But form me "created works fine" in both: run dev and static generated

Answer (score 1):

i've found that for components created() hook of a component runs but not mounted() so try replacing mounted to created if that works

Comment: Yes it work for me

Answer (score -1):

I resolved similar problem, when change type import needed component. Do not flirt with lazy import;)

Was:

```
components: {
    TheError,
    TheHeader,
    TheMain,
    'the-map': () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './TheMap')
},
```

Mounted hook not being called

Now:

```
components: {
    TheError,
    TheHeader,
    TheMain,
    TheMap
}
```

Works!